# The form is sent without validation: php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have tried the following php script to validate the user input.But the form is sent to database without prompting the user to fill the required fields i.e if a user leaves one or more fields empty, the form is submitted without asking to fill the fields.How do stop it from submitting until the conditions for each form field are met?

**here is the code:-**

```
<?php
$fnameErr=$lnameErr=$emailErr=$passwordErr=$cpasswordErr="";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{ 
   if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
     { 
      $fnameErr="First name is Required";
     }
  else
    {
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["lname"]))
    {
    $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
    }
  else
    {
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    }
  else
    {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
    }
  else
    {
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["cpassword"]))
    {
    $cpasswordErr = "Confirm Password";
    }
  else
    {
    $cpassword = $_POST["cpassword"];
    }

    //Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","p11","daot");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    $sql="INSERT INTO registration (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress,Password,ConfirmPassword)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[cpassword]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
}

?> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mastercss.css">
<title>SIGN UP PAGE</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="leftbar">
 </div>
<div class="content">
<h1 class="h1">complete the following form to register</h1>
<fieldset style="width:450px; background:gray;">
<form autocomplete="on" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname"><?php echo $fnameErr;?><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lname"><?php echo $lnameErr;?><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email"><?php echo $emailErr;?><br><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"><?php echo $passwordErr;?><br><br>
  <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="cpassword"><?php echo $cpasswordErr;?><br><br>
  <!--<label for="sex">Sex</label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Female
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
  <label for="select">Birthday</label>
<select name="birthday_Month" id="month">
<option value="0" selected="1">Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
</select>
<select name="birthday_day" id="month">
<option value="0" selected="1">Day</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="birthday_year" id="year">
<option value="0" selected="1">year</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
</select><br><br>-->
<input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" style="width:100: height:100" name="Submit">
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="rightbar"><br><br>
<a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="tw1.jpg">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="fb2.jpg"></a>
</div>
<?php include "footer.php";?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per your code it runs

Comment: If you want to inform user before form submit, you need to use javascript.

Comment: I know i can use a java script but  i want to validate using a PHP code

Answer (score 2):

The form is being submitted without showing validations because it is executing the following line of codes even after executing the validation conditions. You need to avoid executing of the code if any validation is not proper by exiting from the code segment.

```
if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
     { 
      $fnameErr="First name is Required";
      exit;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead

```
if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
     { 
      $fnameErr="First name is Required";
      echo $fnameErr;
exit();
     }
```

and **same for the rest of the conditions.**

Comment: I want to display the error message on the same page i.e to the right side of each text box, not on another page.

Comment: For that you need to use javascript

Comment: Are you sure there is no way in php?

Answer (score 0):

This will display all your errors at once:

In your **PHP**:

```
$error = array(); //save all errors into one array, later we will check if this array is empty to proceed with saving into DB
if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
     { 
      $error['fname']="First name is Required";
     }
  else
    {
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["lname"]))
    {
    $error['lname'] = "Last Name is required";
    }
  else
    {
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
    $error['email'] = "Email is required";
    }
  else
    {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
    $error['password'] = "Password is required";
    }
  else
    {
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["cpassword"]))
    {
    $error['cpassword'] = "Confirm Password";
    }
  else
    {
    $cpassword = $_POST["cpassword"];
    }

if (empty($errors)) {
//if there are no errors, save into DB
//Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","p11","daot");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    $sql="INSERT INTO registration (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress,Password,ConfirmPassword)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[cpassword]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
}
}
```

And in your **HTML**:

```
  <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
  //checking if error message is set, if yes display it
  <input type="text" name="fname"><?php echo isset($error['fname'])?$error['fname']:'' ;?><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lname"><?php echo isset($error['lname'])?$error['lname']:'' ;?><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email"><?php echo isset($error['email'])?$error['email']:'' ;?><br><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"><?php echo isset($error['password'])?$error['password']:'' ;?><br><br>
  <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="cpassword"><?php echo isset($error['cpassword'])?$error['cpassword']:'' ;?><br><br>
```

Comment: It has the same result with my code, nothing is changed.

Comment: Oh wait -.- I thought you wanted to not let it save into database unless all your errors are corrected. Look @user3279301 the HTML code is outputted on the browser only after your PHP code completes, now if you are going to check for errors on PHP, it won't be executed unless and until you re-submit your form (so that again your PHP code is executed first before HTML), thus this becomes a client side validation and if without refresh, then you HAVE to use either AJAX (your PHP code on another form) or use javascript/jQuery to validate. And I wrote a long comment coz I wanted to XD